# Shared vertices in connected components in graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading about graph theory, and especially a paper that mentions: spanning forests. Suppose I have two connected components of a graph, is it allowed that some vertices in the first connected component appears also in the second connected component?

This way I have two spanning forests that could both have shared vertices.

Answer (score 1):

A spanning forest is at least (a) a subgraph, (b) that is spanning [i.e., contains every vertex in the original graph], and (c) is a forest [i.e., no cycles].

So, the original graph, and any spanning forest have the same vertex set (regardless of how many connected components the spanning forest has).

There are two useful definitions of "spanning forest", however.  We could define a spanning forest as:

- any subgraph that has a spanning tree for each connected component in the original graph (useful for enumeration problems).
- any acyclic subgraph on the same vertex set as the original graph (used e.g. for the [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial)).

---

I'm not entirely sure what this means:  "is it allowed that some vertices in the first connected component appears also in the second connected component"  But connected components are disjoint: any vertex belongs to exactly one connected component (and two vertices in different connected components will be in different connected components in any subgraph).